# How does cmp -l show differences?

Tags: linux, gnu

I'm using `cmp (GNU diffutils) 3.7` and I'm confused by the output of `cmp -l/--verbose` ("output byte numbers and differing byte values").

I have two files that are almost identical except for a few bytes at the beginning:

```
$ ls -n x*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 345776 Jun 16 10:41 x-6.xz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 345776 Jun 16 10:04 x-9.xz
$ hexdump -C x-6.xz | head -3
00000000  fd 37 7a 58 5a 00 00 04  e6 d6 b4 46 02 00 21 01  |.7zXZ......F..!.|
00000010  16 00 00 00 74 2f e5 a3  e2 1c bb ef ff 5d 00 39  |....t/.......].9|
00000020  18 4a a7 22 04 94 b3 4a  c8 bc d2 00 4b 8c be aa  |.J."...J....K...|
$ hexdump -C x-9.xz | head -3
00000000  fd 37 7a 58 5a 00 00 04  e6 d6 b4 46 02 00 21 01  |.7zXZ......F..!.|
00000010  1c 00 00 00 10 cf 58 cc  e2 1c bb ef ff 5d 00 39  |......X......].9|
00000020  18 4a a7 22 04 94 b3 4a  c8 bc d2 00 4b 8c be aa  |.J."...J....K...|
$ diff <(hexdump -C x-6.xz) <(hexdump -C x-9.xz)
2c2
< 00000010  16 00 00 00 74 2f e5 a3  e2 1c bb ef ff 5d 00 39  |....t/.......].9|
---
> 00000010  1c 00 00 00 10 cf 58 cc  e2 1c bb ef ff 5d 00 39  |......X......].9|
$
```

What puzzles me is when I do `cmp -l`:

```
$ cmp -l x-6.xz x-9.xz 
    17  26  34
    21 164  20
    22  57 317
    23 345 130
    24 243 314
$
```

It seems to say that byte 17 has value 26 in x-6.xz and value 34 in x-9.xz. That's wrong: in fact, byte 16 (i.e. 0x10) has values 0x16 and 0x1c (22 and 28 respectively). Furthermore, cmp says byte 23 has value 345. How can a byte possibly be more than 255? I must be misinterpreting the meaning of the output, but `man cmp` doesn't seem to say what it is.

Comment: While `man cmp` only shows a concise description, `info diffutils cmp` includes [the details](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/cmp-Options.html#cmp-Options) too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cmp` [counts offsets starting from 1 and displays byte values in octal](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html):

```
17  26  34
```

means that the byte at offset 17 (0x10 in the `hexdump` output, since it starts at 0) has value 026 octal, *i.e.* 22 decimal, in the first file, and 034 octal, *i.e.* 28 decimal, in the second file.

Comment: Thanks! Octal usage is so rare these days, I often forget that many utilities still use it for backwards compatibility.